# Emotion css styled gives me error using same code as example

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, emotion

I am trying to use [Emotion.sh](https://emotion.sh/) in my React test project butI get the following error using the same code as in [example](https://github.com/tkh44/emotion-create-react-app-example)

Things to consider that might have a conflit:
1. I was using npm, now I am using yarn;
2. I already have a small project, and I changed only my App.js to fit exactly the same as the example
3. I am very new to all this =]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andre,  I think your problem relates to emotion's [babel plugin](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/master/docs/install.md) that emotion uses.

Without the babel plugin, your syntax should look like this:

```
const Wrapper = styled('div')`
    text-align: center;
`
```

With the babel plugin, you can use the syntax that you are already using:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
`
```

See the link above for installation instructions and babel config.

Comment: Thanks @Zander, i managed to make it work as you explained. Although I have my .babelrc file with the plugin on it, it seems that its not working.